# Chat solution, that integrates with VBulliten forums

Tags: forum, chat

I'm wondering if there any software that adds the chat capability of on page chat (facebook-like), to the VBulliten forum system, with the following requirements:

1. Requires no plugins (Pure JavaScript) or has alternatives (Uses anyone that available of Flash, or Silverlight of Java).or just throw a link.
2. Integrates with the members system, utilizes the Username, User avatar.
3. Utilizes the friendship featues that is already implemented in VBulliten. So you can see online friends and private-chat with them. And if it supports the public chat rooms it will be better.

I would like to hear about software you've experienced: commercial, property free-ware, or free/open-source. And what services they offer or just a brief about their Pros/Cons from your point of view.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've used [CometChat](http://www.cometchat.com) for my vBulletin forum. It works great and is really feature loaded. I have been using their video chat version and my members love it. As for your question, it integrates with username, avatar as well as friends system of vBulletin.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook like Olark
closes you can get to your requirements plus their service is amazing.

Best solution
LiveZIlla.  Pure JS html. Customizable.  FREE.  Powerful client software.  Chat history, live co-browsing and so much more.  I have nothing but positive things to say about live zilla.

http://www.livezilla.net/home/en/

Comment: They're both for customer support, I want user-to-user chatting.